# Swift - Como fazer e executar um AssyncTask?

Tags: ios, swift

Fiz um app em Android e estou fazendo uma versão dele para IOS atualmente, gostaria de saber como poderia implementar um AssyncTask no Swift e executálo.

## No Android fiz desta forma:

```
public void carregaBanner2(){ new LongOperation3().execute("");}
private class LongOperation3 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public char getChar(char x){return x;}
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            //o que quero executar. . .
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "
                    + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            //depois de executado. . .
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Antes de executar. . .
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você esteja procurando por um recurso chamado Grand Central Dispatch (GCD), que cuida da concorrência no Swift. Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/).